# Unable to Transfer input value to ASP.net textbox value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to transfer input value in ASP.net textbox in javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var val = localStorage.getItem("menusave");
    document.getElementById("<%= txt1.ClientID %>").value = val;
    document.getElementById("city").value = val;
</script>

<input type="text" id="city" name="city" />   <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: when is your javascript getting triggerred. bind it to a onblur or onchange event of textbox to transfer value to other control.

Comment: no it will appear onload of page

Comment: The script should be called after the creation of those elements, if it isn't, then you'll get an exception.

Comment: move your scripts to bottom of page, or use document.ready event of jquery

Comment: no actually problem is val value is set to input but when input have runat=server that value not showing

Comment: Put your script at the end of page.

Comment: have you checked the input id in view source while you kept runat=Server..

it may render with other name like ctl100_city or something else..

Comment: Have you checked if the var has the correct value?

Comment: thanks  Sunil Gudivada

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('<%= txtCity.ClientID %>').value = 'whatever';
}

<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

If you are using ASP.NET 4 or above, you can also modify the ClientIDMode of the page to static. In this way, your ids won't be modified.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="myPage.aspx.cs" ClientIDMode="Static" %>

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('txtCity').value = 'whatever';
}

<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JQuery?
If yes use this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });
```

if you are not using JQuery do like this:

```
<body onload="CallFcn()" >
<form id="form1" runat="server" >
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
function CallFcn() {
    var val = localStorage.getItem("menusave");
    document.getElementById("<%= txt1.ClientID %>").value = val;
    document.getElementById("city").value = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create this elements

```
<input type="text" id="city" name="city" />   
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" Text="dfdsd"></asp:TextBox>
```

then add Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     localStorage.setItem("menusave", "Test");
     var val=localStorage.getItem("menusave");
     document.getElementById('<%= txt1.ClientID %>').value =val;
     document.getElementById("city").value = val;
</script>
```

result like

[image]